# update rows if data is missing from other tables based on conditions python pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a df with 4 columns and create another column(production per RunTime) using Prod and RT columns. I use this table as a reference table.

Sample reference Df:

```
data = {'Machine': ['M1','M2','M2','M4','M4'], 'Type': ['A1', 'D1', 'D2', 'A2','A5'],'Prod': [100, 150, 180, 300,120],'RT': [43200,12000,3900,36000,4000]}
df=pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data)
df['Prod/RT']=df['Prod']/df['RT']
df
```

[image]

Below table is my day-to-day table. What I want to do is if 'Prod/RT' column contains **missing values** check the reference table for that ****particular row's Machine and Type combination** if its available update its value from the reference table and if its not available update it as 0.002**

```
datanew = {'Machine': ['M1','M2','M2','M4','M44','M55'], 'Type': ['A1', 'D1', 'D2', 'A2','A5','B4'],'Prod': [200, 0, 180, 0,0,0],'RT': [43200,0,3900,0,0,0]}
df1=pd.DataFrame.from_dict(datanew)
df1['Prod/RT']=df1['Prod']/df1['RT']
df1
```

[image]

for example:

2nd row 'Prod/RT' is NaN:    Machine ID:M2 & Type D1 >its avaible in refrence table and update empty value as 0.012500

again 4th row:Machine ID :    M4 & Type A2 >its avaible in refrence table and update empty value as 0.008333

5th and 4th row: Those machine and Type combination not in reference table. So update its value as default value(0.002).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Target the actual column, first fill with the values from the original dataframe before running `fillna` with `0.002`:

```
group = ['Machine', 'Type']

df1.assign(**{"Prod/RT" : lambda df1: df1.set_index(group)['Prod/RT']
                                         .fillna(df.set_index(group)['Prod/RT'])
                                         .fillna(0.002)
                                         .array})


  Machine Type  Prod     RT   Prod/RT
0      M1   A1   200  43200  0.004630
1      M2   D1     0      0  0.012500
2      M2   D2   180   3900  0.046154
3      M4   A2     0      0  0.008333
4     M44   A5     0      0  0.002000
5     M55   B4     0      0  0.002000
```

Comment: can you please explain the code? why did you use **??

Comment: The key `Prod/RT` is not acceptable within the `assign` clause ( it is not an acceptable key ). The workaraound is to pass a dictionary instead and `unpack` it, which is what the `**` does

Comment: Got the point. but why did you say that Prod/RT not an acceptable key?

Comment: Assign uses kwargs which accepts only strings . Prod/RT isn't recognised as a string, so it throws an error. Hence the workaround.

Answer (score 1):

Let's try using [`DataFrame.combine_first`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.combine_first.html#pandas-dataframe-combine-first)

```
print(
    df1.set_index(['Machine', 'Type']).combine_first(
        df.set_index(['Machine', 'Type'])).fillna(0.002).reset_index()
)
```

---

```
  Machine Type   Prod       RT   Prod/RT
0      M1   A1  200.0  43200.0  0.004630
1      M2   D1    0.0      0.0  0.012500
2      M2   D2  180.0   3900.0  0.046154
3      M4   A2    0.0      0.0  0.008333
4      M4   A5  120.0   4000.0  0.030000
5     M44   A5    0.0      0.0  0.002000
6     M55   B4    0.0      0.0  0.002000
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @sushanth. What if i have various columns in df1, but only want to update Prod/RT column from df1. for example, df1 have another set of columns speed, weight and etc